# How to Get BootStrapper.exe work in Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, bootstrapper, application-start

I download bootstrapper.exe from http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/, I manage to get it work in local IIS.
At Application_Start() and use Process.Start()

But at Windows Azure, not work at all.
I am sure file is there and no error message.

but no file download and unzipped. I tried both "local resource" folder or local folder

Does anyone here have a working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to have the bootstrapper.exe as part of your project (Add -> Existing Item -> browse to the bootstrapper.exe & .config include both of them). For the properties of these files, you must set "Build Action" to "None" and "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always".

Now you can use following code to run the bootstrapper (I do it like that and it works):

```
      internal void SomethingWithBootStrapper()
    {
        //
        Trace.TraceInformation("Trying to install agent...");
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "bootstrapper.exe");
        psi.Arguments = @"-get http://some_url_to_download_something.com/path/to/file.zip -lr $lr(YourLocalResourceKeyHere) -unzip $lr(YourLocalResourceKeyHere)\extract -run $lr(YourLocalResourceKeyHere)\extract\Setup.exe  -args /some /args /for_the_setup.exe -block";
        Trace.WriteLine("Calling " + psi.FileName + " " + psi.Arguments + " ...");
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.ErrorDialog = false;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        // run elevated
        psi.Verb = "runas";
        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                string outString = string.Empty;
                // use ansynchronous reading for at least one of the streams
                // to avoid deadlock
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                {
                    outString += e.Data;
                };
                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                // now read the StandardError stream to the end
                // this will cause our main thread to wait for the
                // stream to close (which is when ffmpeg quits)
                string errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Trace.WriteLine(outString);
                Trace.TraceError(errString);
                this._isInitialized = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(e.Message);
            this._isInitialized = false;
        }
    }
```

Please note, that this is 100% tested and working code!

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion remind me, I forget the "BootStrapper.exe.config" file. Since it works in local IIS, I never thought about this file anymore :(

Comment: @astaykov - out of curiousity, why don't you put the command in a bat file and call from a startup task?  That was the initial use case I built bootstrapper for.

Comment: @dunnry, I don't know him, but for me, I do not use .bat file is because I need to get some arguments at run-time. Thank you for the good tool you build.

Comment: Dunnry, I can use the bootstrapper in a far more complicated scenario, then just a startup task ;) Of course I use also in a batch file for startup task also.
Eric, you can get a lot of arguments in the startup task, but I agree that there are some arguments you don't have until runtime :)

Comment: Understood.  If you can drop me a line, I might be able to help you make bootstrapper more valuable.  My endgoal is that you don't have to ever call it by Process.Start(). :)